# How to prevent Google Drive API v3 from sending a notification email when giving writer permissions?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm able to give `writer` permissions using the Google Drive API (v3). This is the endpoint:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/permissions"
```

The [API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) says that I should use `sendNotificationEmail: false` (note, this is a boolean not a string), which is what I'm doing (in v2 this was called `sendNotificationEmails`).

[image]

However, after the call I still get the email from Google saying I've been invited to edit a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `sendNotificationEmail: false` works as intended, there is one small detail:

It is a request parameter that goes outside of the resource body.

I am not sure which language your are using, if e.g. Javascript, the request would be:

```
gapi.client.drive.permissions.create({
      "fileId": "XXX",
      "sendNotificationEmail": false,
      "resource": {
        "role": "writer",
        "type": "user",
        "emailAddress": "test@gmail.com"
      }
    })
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! So simple 